# How do I authenticate with the Stack Overflow API

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c#-5.0, stackexchange-api

How do I authenticate with Stack Overflow in C# (Windows RT)? I'm not sure how to do this, so any example would be great.

Comment: Yes. I want to make a program for Windows 8 in C # to work with SO
Do not know how to do authentication.

Comment: I can not deal with the API for winRT/C#.

Comment: Is SO StackOverflow site or something else ?

Comment: You question is too broad. Please specify what have you tried so far and what problems or errors are you having.

Comment: Yes. As for C#/WinRT make authorization StackOverflow.

Comment: Found [API](https://github.com/NickLarsen/StacMan) for working with Stack Overflow. I can not understand

Comment: @KovalenkoTaras You will need to ask much more specific question. What don't you understand about the API?

Comment: Which class is responsible for the authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `WebAuthenticationBroker` to authenticate through OAuth 2. There is a sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122). You might need to get some documentation for the Stack Exchange API from [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Comment: And there are no ready-made API for working with it?

Comment: I think there isn't much you need after you look at these two links. In fact I will try to do it myself since I was thinking about doing an SO app before.